# Как расставить паузы?

Tags: пунктуация

Как расставить паузы так, чтобы вместо двоеточия стояла запятая?

> Не отходи от меня: мне так с тобой отрадно.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ДЗ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**Не отходи от меня, мне так с тобой отрадно.**

В этом бессоюзном сложном предложении можно использовать **оба знака,** при этом при постановке **запятой второе предложение распространяет первое, а при постановке двоеточия второе предложение обозначает причину первого.** Такие предложения являются предложениями неоднородного состава, в отличие от от однородных предложений с перечислительной интонацией и обязательной запятой (шумел ветер, гремел гром).

Интонация различна: обычная пауза **при запятой** и увеличенная (предупредительная/пояснительная) пауза с неполным понижением голоса при **двоеточии**.

(Материал соответствует курсу лекций "Синтаксис современного русского языка").

Обратим внимание на то, что в обычной речи мы далеко не всегда обозначаем причинно-следственные отношения, например: Погода дождливая, гуляем редко.